# Sending 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' and other headers via CURL - other ways?

Tags: php, curl, header, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I have, of course, read several questions with exactly this asked, but I have to say it didn't work for me at all. What I am about to accomplish is

- sending 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' header via PHP and curl
- sending other http request headers via PHP and curl

provided solutions didn't work for me.

**How do I know I'm not sending right http request headers?**

Simply by

(1)comparing real headers generated by XMLHttpRequest(triggering JQuery click) and those simulated by PHP and curl in Firefox add-on Live HTTP headers

(2)Print_r() -ing $_SERVER variable in target script

**What do I get that is incorrect/below my expectations?**

First and most important: 
Firefox Live HTTP headers does not capture my headers (just like they don't exists).

Second, by print_r($_SERVER):

if I get anything of simulated headers at all, I get `[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest` - **not the:** `[X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest`. 
That problem persists almost for any header I send via curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header) - any of these is being prefixed with 'HTTP' ('Header1: value1' - I get 'HTTP_HEADER1').

I'm using XAMPP with PHP version 5.4.7, CURL 7.24.0 .

Before I ask if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible or maybe not and say thanks in advance for responses, it's not bad idea to provide my code - *one of many* code solutions that I've tried.

```
$curl_header = array('X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest');
$data = "name=miloshio"; // just to be sure I'm doing the POST request
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Sum of my questions:

1. Is it possible to send exactly 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
   header via PHP and curl?
2. Is it possible to avoid attaching 'HTTP_' prefix to custom headers
   send by PHP and curl?
3. Are there well-known limitations in matter of using PHP and curl?

Comment: Your method helped me a lot. I faked an xmlhttprequest using URL and PHP and your code. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firefox Live HTTP headers won't show your headers as they're sent by the server to another server and not to the client(browser).
2. Curl send the headers correctly, using [CURLOPT_PROXY](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) You can try to put curl traffic through a debuging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if You're using windows for development, I'm sure there are linux alternatives
3. If you try to get the headers from $*SERVER variable, they will be prefixed with HTTP*, you can use [apache_request_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) to get the headers without HTTP_ prefix.